# Pythonic Way To Draw Polygon

Tags: iterator, draw, python, polygon

Specifically, I have a list of points. I want to connect these points together to create a polygon.

The obvious way to do this is the C-style:

```
 39 def drawPoly(poly):
 40     for i in range(0, len(poly)):
 41         p1 = poly[i]
 42         p2 = poly[i + 1]
 43         canvas.create_line(blah)
```

Is there a way to do this that is more pythonic?

Comment: I think `p2 = poly[i + 1]` may give you an `IndexError`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, since `create_line` can take a list of points, all you need to do is copy the first two elements and stuff 'em on the end:

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, mainloop
master = Tk()
points = [10, 10, 50, 10, 50, 50, 10, 50 ]
c = Canvas(master, width=200, height=100)
c.pack()
c.create_line(points + points[0:2], fill = "red")
mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize I could do this.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: I think I misunderstood your example, `poly` is a list of tuples correct? I'm changing my answer to reflect [ckhan's observations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10185041/5987) that `create_line` is a Tk canvas method, and your polygon is probably not closed.

```
def drawPoly(poly):
    x1 = y1 = None
    for x2, y2 in poly + poly[0]:
        if x1 is not None:
            canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)
        x1, y1 = x2, y2
```